# Fetching Entities from DB in a PropertyEditor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

When using PropertyEditors with Spring MVC is it bad to have them fetch entities from the database? Should I instead create an empty entity and set its Id.

For instance for the entity Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements GenericEntity<Integer>{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    /** More properties here **/
}
```

Is it a bad idea to fetch the Entity in the PropertyEditor below with the following GenericEntityEditor:

```
public class GenericEntityEditor<ENTITY extends GenericEntity<Integer>> extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private GenericDao<ENTITY, Integer> genericDao;

    public GenericEntityEditor(GenericDao<ENTITY, Integer> genericDao) {
        this.genericDao = genericDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        setValue(genericDao.findById(Integer.valueOf(text)));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        ENTITY entity = (ENTITY) getValue();
        if(entity == null) {
            return null;
        } 

        return String.valueOf(entity.getId());
    }
}
```

Which can be bound in the controller:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    /** Some Service-layer resources **/

    @Resource
    private EmployeeDao employeeDao; // implements GenericDao<ENTITY, Integer> genericDao

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Employee.class, new GenericEntityEditor(employeeDao));
    }

    /** Some request mapped methods **/

}
```

Is it preferred to use a more specific approach with a EmployeeEditor and have it just instantiate an Employee entity and set its id:

```
public class EmployeeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(Integer.valueOf(text));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        Employee employee = (Employee) getValue();
        if(employee == null) {
            return null;
        } 

        return String.valueOf(employee.getId());
    }
}
```

This way we do not do a roundtrip to the DB each time an Employee exists on a Form, but I'm unsure if this works as expected with Hibernate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is legal. I used this technice for some time, and it worked well.

But Spring 3.0 has a better concept. So called [Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) (Reference Chapter [5.5 Spring 3 Type Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s05.html))

This converters work like one way property editors. But they are Stateless, and because of this more performat, and can be reuesed!

---

Added:
There is an [not (yet) documented](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7461) feature of Spring 3.0.>3: the org.springframework.core.convert.support.IdToEntityConverter

It is automatically registered in the ConversationService by the ConcersationServiceFactory.

This IdToEntityConverter will automatically convert everything (Object) to an Entity, if the entity!! has a static method `find<entityName>` which has one parameter and the return type is of type of the entity.

```
/**
 * Converts an entity identifier to a entity reference by calling a static finder method
 * on the target entity type.
 *
 * <p>For this converter to match, the finder method must be public, static, have the signature
 * <code>find[EntityName]([IdType])</code>, and return an instance of the desired entity type.
 *
 * @author Keith Donald
 * @since 3.0
 */
```

If you have doubt how to implement such a static finder method in your entity. Then have a look at Spring Roo generated entities.

Comment: good answer as always (+1) but you keep inventing words (performat, reuesed). Do you know that there are spell checkers available for most browsers? :-)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: My browsers spell checker is for german language. But I guess I should change it to english.

Comment: I'd suggest that because your German spelling is a lot better than your english spelling. Or use a dedicated browser just for SO :-)

Comment: Thanks! Good answer @Ralph. We are using Spring 2.5.6 at the moment, but I've experimented with using 3.0.5 and there seem to be little problems doing this upgrade so this is yet another reason to do the switch.