# Spring HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (when adding date input)

Tags: spring, jsp, http, spring-mvc, http-status-code-400

When I add a date field on the jsp form I get this error, but it works fine without it.

**Request**

```
http://localhost:8080/myTasks/docreatetask?task=hi+there&description=stucked+here&date=2014-02-21&idTaskCategory=1&idTaskPriority=1&idTaskState=1&pending=1&idUser=0&idUser_responsible=0&evaluation=aaaaaa
```

**Partly form.jsp**

```
<form method="GET"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/docreatetask">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Task</td>
            <td><input name="task" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><textarea name="description"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td><input name="date" type="date"/></td>
        </tr>
```

Partly **Task.java** component

```
@Component("task")
public class Task {

    private long id;
    private String task;
    private String description;
    private Date date;
    private Date deadline;
    private Category category;
    private Priority priority;
    private State state;
    private User user;
    private User userResponsible;
    private String evaluation;
    private Date timestamp;
    private int pending;
```

Partly **Task controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/createtask")
public String createTask(Model model) {
    List<Category> categories = taskService.getCategories();
    List<Priority> priorities = taskService.getPriorities();
    List<State> states = taskService.getStates();
    List<User> users = taskService.getUsers();

    model.addAttribute("categories",categories);
    model.addAttribute("priorities",priorities);
    model.addAttribute("states",states);
    model.addAttribute("users",users);

    return "createtask";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/docreatetask", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String doCreateTask(Model model, Task task) {
    System.out.println(">TaskController doCreateTask " + task);

    return "taskcreated";
}
```

Any idea what this can be?

Thanks in advance!

---

**New extra information about the error**
I added some validations annotations and I got new information about the error.

> Field error in object 'task' on field 'date': rejected value
>   [01/01/2001]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.task.date,typeMismatch.date,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [task.date,date]; arguments []; default message [date]]; default
>   message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String'
>   to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'date'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type java.lang.String to type
>   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date
>   for value '01/01/2001'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse '01/01/2001']

Comment: in pojo class if for date field I am using -- import java.sql.Date , I was getting same above exception .

In pojo we have to use -- import java.util.Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two probems:

- 1 the parameters (idTaskCategory, idTaskPriority, idXXX) does not match the `Task` fields. (this is not the cause for your problem, but it will just not work. And when you change the names so that they match, it problem is that your request contains ids, but your `Task` expect objects. So you need to make the task expect ids too, or you need to register some converter)
- 2 (I think that this is the problem), I expect that **the date format / converter does not accept the submitted date format**. Add `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` to all date fields.

<strike>I think one problem could be that you use the http method `GET`. A GET Request send the parameter by using the URL query string (the stuff after the `?`).
But the total length of the URL is technical restricted by browsers, chaches, webservers.
So one cause for the problem could be, that the URL gets to long, if you have a lot of paramters or a "long" value (for example a long description).</strike>
 (*this is correct, but not the cause*)

So I would recommend to use http method `POST` instead. -- And using `POST` is the better verb for an Request that changes something on the server (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) .

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I already know that, but unfortunately that's not the problem.
I'm using GET to be able to see the querystring. I will use POST when I know how to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Joe: You are right, I have overlooked the posted request example. - But I think I have spotted the probem now.

Comment: Problem 1, I could be an error but if I take input date out the jsp, the controller get the object Task but with a null date, that is ok for now.
Problem 2, I tried with and without that validation, and even different kind of validation like "dd/mm/yyyy"... and it still the same problem comes up :(

Comment: I got new info that I added in the question maybe that help us something

Comment: you were right, it worked with @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"). Maybe the capital MM ;)

Comment: About Problem 1, I have a class property instead an id for some properties but I'm getting id from the form. Should I change properties for id long in the class?

Comment: I already resolved that as well. Thanks for your help @Ralph!

Comment: @Joe: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593581/fetching-entities-from-db-in-a-propertyeditor -- (There must be an other question and answer somewhere where I have explained how to do this with an converter, but I can't find it. Maybe you have more luck)

Answer (score 0):

A long time back I also faced this problem.

I solved it using:

```
@InitBinder

protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, false));
}
```